# How to make charts with controls in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a point by point graph, how it could be done more efficiently. I would like to get the following graphic

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[]
    \draw[->,line width = 1.5pt] (3,3.2) -- (0.5,0.5) node[left]{$x_1$};
    \draw[->,line width = 1.5pt] (3,3.2) -- (3,7.5) node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[line width = 1.5pt] (3,3.2) -- (5.7,3.2) ;
    \draw[->,line width = 1.5pt] (8.6,3.2) -- (10.5,3.2) node[right]{$x_2$};
   \draw[red,line width = 1.5pt] (4.5,0.85) .. controls(4.28,1.2).. (4.28,1.5) .. controls(4.33,1.7).. (4.5,1.85) .. controls(5,2.2) and (5.25,2.4) .. (5.5,2.9) .. controls(5.8,3.2) and (6.25,4.8).. (6.4,5) .. controls(6.7,5.5).. (7,5.75) .. controls(7.45,5.91).. (7.9,5.7);
   % \node[circle (2.5pt)] at (2,5.3) {};
    \draw [fill=black] (5.45,1.55) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (6.8,1.85) circle (2.5pt);
    \node at (6.5,1.5) [left]{$S$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're on the right path, but you give too many points. For this shape, 5 points should be enough (except for the dashed arc in the background). Using a vector drawing software could help to create the shape and extract the curves.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very quick sketch done *by hand*, which explains its low accuracy with your needs, but it could help you start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [purple,line width=2pt]
                (0,2)   .. controls ++(0.25,1)  and ++(-0.8,-2) ..
                (3,5.5) .. controls ++(0.8,2)   and ++(-2,-0.1) ..
                (4.5,11).. controls ++(2,0.1)   and ++(-0.2,1.5)..
                (7,6)   .. controls ++(0.2,-1.5)and ++(-0.8,1)  ..
                (8.5,3) .. controls ++(0.8,-1)  and ++(1.8,0.3) ..
                (5.5,2) .. controls ++(-1.8,-.3)and ++(1.5,-.25)..
                (2,0)   .. controls ++(-1.5,.25)and ++(-.25,-1) ..
                (0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I get some free time, I would be able to refine and complete it but try for yourself.

[image: Beziers curve]

Answer (score 1):

A handy approach can be to insert the graphic that you want to trace as a `\node` with `\includegraphics` in the `tikzpicture` environment. Then you can add paths that trace the image. `TikzEdt` (http://www.tikzedt.org/) is particularly useful for this. It has a bezier drawing tool and drawings recompile automatically when the `tex` file changes. The handles for the controls snap to a grid so it's relatively easy to just move those handles around until the curve matches what you are trying to trace. Here's a screenshot of the `TikzEdt` window showing the drawing with the handles for each curve.

[image]

I usually finish up doing some manually editing of the code that `TikzEdt` generates. All in, this took about 10 minutes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.append style={line width=2pt,line cap=round}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Ex240.png}};
%Axes
\draw (-2.7,-2) -- (-1.5,-0.8) -- (-1.5,2)
                   (-1.5,-0.8) -- (-0.3,-0.8) (1.25,-0.8)  -- (2.6,-0.8);
%Hill
\draw[red] (0.7,0.6) .. controls (-0.1,0.4) and (0.2,-0.3) .. 
           (-0.6,-1.3) .. controls (-1.1,-1.4) and (-1,-2.2) .. 
           (0.1,-1.9) .. controls (0.5,-1.6) and (0.7,-1.5) .. 
           (1.5,-1.5) .. controls (1.7,-1.5) and (1.7,-1.3) .. 
           (1.5,-1.3) .. controls (1,-0.9) and (1.4,0.3) .. 
           (0.7,0.6);
\draw[green] (0.7,0.6) .. controls (0.3,0.3) and (0.7,-1.1) .. (-0.3,-1.5);
%Dashed arc
\draw[blue,dashed] (-0.6,-1.3) arc(115:65:2.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent approach (I usually do that with... erm... Word) +1